# Could not connect to Tor control port. Mac OS

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

Had no problems using Tor Browser for 4 years or so then all of a sudden 'could not connect to Tor control port'. El Capitan 10.11.6 - Tor 6.05.

I've tried deleting and re-installing Tor, turning off Firewall, running virus checks, disk maintenance, Mac Clean etc still same error.

The one noticeable things is a slight delay as Tor starts.

I can't paste the Tor log because it doesn't generate one - reads '(0) logs ready to be copied to clipboard'. If I click 'settings' I just get 'Waiting for Tor to start' ...then 'Could not connect to Tor control port' again.

I have not recently installed any new software of system updates so no real change in the environment - any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have it so it opens a program when you click on a magnet link at all?

Comment: No, just a double click on the Tor icon from the apps menu, i've checked the mac's port usage and nothing is using 9150. As mentioned in the first comment, there's a real delay before Tor attempts to open - as if its possibly clashing with something else but not error message occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered there:
[Tor Launcher: Could not connect to Tor control port](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12699/tor-launcher-could-not-connect-to-tor-control-port)

OS X, Yosemite 10.10.5, same problem.

I've deleted Tor application, deleted `~/Library/Application Support` folder, installed new stable version and now it works.

Comment: Bingo!! ...well done sir - problem solved, many thanks